# pyspark:ORC does not support type conversion from file type string (1) to reader type array<struct>(1)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, orc

I read a orc file stored locally using pyspark==3.0.0dev2.
The Schema of the original file is as follows：

```
root
 |-- dat: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- passenger_num: string (nullable = true)
 |-- is_agency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- time_stamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lng: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- speed: double (nullable = true)
```

I explode the 'coordinates' column use

```
explodeDF = df.select(explode("coordinates").alias("cor"))
flattenDF = explodeDF.selectExpr("cor.time_stamp", "cor.lng", "cor.lat", "cor.speed")
```

After explode the original data, I get a new flattenDF. But when I show it use `flattenDF.show()`, I get error as follows:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o236.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 54, WIN-VQVQVO99M5A, executor driver): org.apache.orc.impl.SchemaEvolution$IllegalEvolutionException: ORC does not support type conversion from file type string (1) to reader type array<struct<time_stamp:bigint,lng:double,lat:double,speed:double>> (1)
```

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some solutions:
I read the original orc file named `a`, write it directly to the local file system, named `a_new`, and then read `a_new` and run the code, work perfectly without error. So, I guess this is a version problem.

When I changed the version to spark 2.4.5, something magic happened. The code would not report an error.

So,when you got the same error as me, you can check if your spark version is 3.0. and change it to 2.4.5.